# Bad request with Acquia Dev Desktop2 overriding installation

Tags: acquia-dev-desktop

I use Acquia Dev Desktop2 on Mac for php7.0.
I think that it is the previous version.
I was waiting for the upgrade to use php7.1, but there was no announcement in check for update menu.
I have no choice, so I downloaded it and overwrite install.
The bad request will be displayed on all local sites.
Phpmyadmin of all sites will be displayed correctly.
What is the solution?

What I can think of is using underscores for site addresses.

test_drupal8_mockup1.dd:8083

In order to remove the underscore, I edited vhosts.conf and restarted apache.
'But request' was not improved.

Comment: After rewriting ServerName in vhosts.conf, and I restart Acquia Dev Desktop 2 App, ServerName will be restored.
Which file should I edit to change ServerName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative solution, I tried to add the following setting setting to httpd.conf.

```
<IfVersion> = 2.4.25>
 HttpProtocolOptions unsafe
</ IfVersion>
```

'Bad request' message is solved.
The reason was that ServerName contained underscores.